# Autoloading / injecting namespaced classes in extbase correctly

Tags: dependency-injection, typo3, autoload, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I am integrating a few php classes into a TYPO3 6.2 extension created with extension_builder. The extbase version is also 6.2.

I think I followed the indications on https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Autoloading/Index.html

- Namespaced the classes (correctly?)
- As I think I'm using namespaces, I didn't name the Classes in the form of `Tx_MyExtension_Utility_FooBar`
- Injected the class with `@inject` annotation as suggested on https://wiki.typo3.org/Dependency_Injection

These are the concerned files:

**EXT:apievents/Classes/Utility/SomeClass.php:**

```
class SomeClass {
  // do something
}
```

**EXT:apievents/Classes/Controller/ImportCommandController.php**

```
<?php
namespace STUBR\Apievents\Controller;

// Copyright, Package, License ...

class ImportCommandController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\CommandController {

    /**
    * @var \namespace STUBR\Apievents\Utility\SomeClass
    * @inject
    */
    protected $SomeClass;
    // do something
 }
```

Which when I run it (it's a scheduler task) gives me the nicely formatted error

> Execution of task "Extbase CommandController Task (extbase)" failed
>   with the following message: Could not analyse class:namespace
>   STUBR\Apievents\Utility\SomeClass maybe not loaded or no autoloader?

So something must be missing for the class to be loaded. 
What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your injection code to

```
/**
 * @var \STUBR\Apievents\Utility\SomeClass
 * @inject
 */
 protected $someClass;
```

In the `@var` annotation you just specify the fully qualified class name. Nothing more. Nothing less. Make sure that you have the namespace set in you utility class as well

```
namespace STUBR\Apievents\Utility;
```

Comment: ahhh... now the namespace hijacks other Predefined PHP classes in that class, like `throw new Exception('Text');` or `new SoapClient()`: `Fatal error: Class 'STUBR\Apievents\Utility\SoapClient' not found`. Do I have to inject those too?

Comment: Ah I think I've got it: have to escape the predefined classes to the global space, as such: `new \SoapClient()`

Comment: Yes correct, if you dont append the \ php will look for the class in the current namespace.